# wpa_supplicant for LG C710h that enables ad hoc networking

Tags: android, root

I've been looking for a while now trying to find a wpa_supplicant that will work on my LG C710h and enable detection of ad hoc networks. I've tried 4 or 5 that I found on forums and none of them work, I try to start my WiFi but it just hangs and then shuts off.

The current version of my wpa_supplicant is 0.5.11 but I tried [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=754961), [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1777413), and [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1806937) just to name a few, and none worked.

My method for swapping the wpa_supplicant files is as follows:

- download zip and unzip in sdcard/download
- shut off WiFi
- open cmd7.exe
- `adb shell`
- `cp sdcard/download/wpa_supplicant system/bin/wpa_supplicant.new`
- `mv system/bin/wpa_supplicant system/bin/wpa_supplicant.old`
- `mv system/bin/wpa_supplicant.new system/bin/wpa_supplicant`
- restart wifi

Has anyone found a wpa_suppliment that can enable detection of ad hoc networks for this device? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance for the helpful comments or suggestions.